# Check if any substring from array appear in string?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following query:

```
select case when count(*)>0 then true else false end
from tab
where param in ('a','b') and position('T' in listofitem)>0
```

This checks if `'T'` exists in the column `listofitem` and if it does the count is > 0. Basically it's a search for sub string.

This works well in this private case. However my real case is that I have `text[]` called `sub_array` meaning multiple values to check. How can I modify the query to handle the `sub_array` type? I prefer to have it in a query rather than a function with a LOOP.

**What I actualy need is:**

```
select case when count(*)>0 then true else false end
from tab
where param in ('a','b') and position(sub_array in listofitem)>0
```

This is not working since `sub_array`  is of type `Text[]`

Comment: try `unnest`ing the array

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [`unnest()` function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html) to expand your array & `bool_and()` (or `bool_or()` -- this depends on what you want match: *all* array elements, or *at least one*) to [aggregate](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html):

```
select count(*) > 0
from   tab
where  param in ('a','b')
and    (select bool_and(position(u in listofitem) > 0)
        from   unnest(sub_array) u)
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood. The 'T' is just an example. I need to replace it with the sub_array. If sub_array contains '3a', 'c','h' than I need to search these three strings inside the tab table.

Comment: @avi the main idea did not change. use unnest to expand & aggregation to summarize. the actual formulas do not matter that much. (I updated my answer).

Comment: Thanks. You have a syntax error near the 0... one brackets too many. However this still doesn't work in all cases. If My rows are ''28713"
and "-1,37561,37560" . When sub_array='37588','37560' it doesn't find the 37560. But if sub_array=37561,37560  it works.

Comment: @avi yes, that's exactly the case I noted when proposed to use either `bool_and` or `bool_or`. If you need only one element in the array to be matched, use `bool_or`

Comment: bool_or is excellent. Is there a way to ignore specific sub-string? for example if u='-1' ?

Comment: @avi use `where u <> -1` in the sub-select. `u` is both a table alias & a column alias in my example. if you want different aliases, you could use the `from unnest(sub_array) table_alias(column_alias)` form.

Answer (score 0):

A brute force method would be to convert the array to a string:

```
select (count(*) > 0) as flag
from tab
where param in ('a','b') and
      array_to_string(listofitem, '') like '%T%';
```

I should note that comparing `count(*)` is not the most efficient way of doing this.  I would suggest instead:

```
select exists (select 1
               from tab
               where param in ('a','b') and
                     array_to_string(listofitem, '') like '%T%'
              ) as flag;
```

This stops the logic at the first match, rather than counting all matching rows.

Comment: How do I replace the %T% to variable? I can't write '%sub_array%'. By the way it doesn't stop the logic at the first match. The inner query will return multiple rows that contains 1.